# Undefined index: REDIRECT_STATUS in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have successfully created a .htaccess file which works and am redirecting all error codes (400, 403, 404, 405, 408, 500, 502, 504) to a common error-page.php.
I am using **$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]**; to detect the error code, however when the page is navigated to on an error, as should happen, I receive a **Undefined index: REDIRECT_STATUS** error. Is there some config, or other variable I need to set ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such predefined variable in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: @DanGrossman - according to this, there is: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#105602

Comment: check the comments on the page dan linked and you will see that REDIRECT_STATUS _is_ a valid variable.

Comment: I see a comment from a user on some web server setup that is injecting that value into the environment. It's not provided by PHP, or it'd be in the documentation with those that are.

Comment: This status is set not consistently. I have not dive into it, so I can't tell you the rule when it is or isn't set.

Comment: I've checked my own php setup up (v 5.3.6) and the variable _is_ set.  But I haven't yet found how that is the case. Now I too am curious.

Comment: It's mentioned here, but not all variables mentioned there ace actually set. I think they are talking about variables accessible in the .htaccess file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#variables

Answer (score 4):

You could just try using something along the lines of...

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-page.php?status=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error-page.php?status=500
```

Then handle the error page from there accordingly with $_GET.

Comment: Thanks @Tynarus, I'd rather not go that way.
So if you guys find out any more, you knows where I lives :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#configuration):

> When redirecting to a local URL, additional environment variables are
>   set so that the response can be further customized. They are not sent
>   to external URLs.

So if your ErrorDocument directive uses a URL, `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]` will not be available.

Instead of this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/error-page.php
```

Do this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-page.php
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere that says when this was added to Apache, so I'm not sure what version is required for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could help? It works for me for almost all undefined index error I encountered.

```
<?PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Comment: @KenK ItayMoav Dan Grossman
Whoa, this is the most reply I have EVER got, wow, I'm excited, thanks for all contributing, I was starting to believe the variable is not defined, but then seen code where it is used.
So if you guys find out any more, you knows where I lives :)